# What is ExpectationE and what does it do?

Tags: functions, probability-or-statistics, symbols, built-in-symbols

I just found the symbol `ExpectationE` with autocomplete.

[image]

Rendered the symbol is

[image]

Searching the documentation and the internet leads to nothing. Does somebody know what this symbol does and what its purpose is?

Comment: It seems to print a funny symbol in the front end.  Try `ExpectationE[x]`.

Comment: @QuantumDot, you can also get the same symbol with `\[ExpectationE]`. It looks like the Rx recipe symbol used in pharmacy, but instead with an Ex. It is a script E joined to a small and subset x.

Comment: Presumably it provides notation for the [expectation symbol](https://blogs.ethz.ch/kowalski/2009/02/05/expectation-symbol/)?

Comment: @Mr.Wizard That's exactly what it is...

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It doesn't do anything, it just formats in a certain way.  You can assign your own definition if you like.

References:

- [Operators without builtin meanings](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/tutorial/OperatorsWithoutBuiltInMeanings.html)